# Missing encrypted Exact Online password with device-specific key warning itgendhb079

Tags: exact-online, invantive-data-hub

Customer is running Invantive Data Hub and has recently upgraded. The batch file used to include the following:

```
/password:PASSWORD
```

But the use of unencrypted seems no longer supported; I must provide an encrypted password instead. Invantive Data Hub reports:

```
itgendhb079 This script uses a non-encrypted password. Please use an encrypted password instead.
```

How can I encrypt the password? I seem unable to find a menu option for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an encrypted version of the password by executing the following in the Query Tool or Data Hub:

```
local encrypt password
```

and then pressing enter (Data Hub) or ctrl+enter (Query Tool).

A window will appear with the currently used password filled-in when available, signalled by ***.

Please note that the encrypted password is encrypted using a device-specific key. So you can only use it on the device on which you generated the encrypted password.

Comment: Note you can use the dummy provider to log on to if you have no other platform to connect to.